# how to find integer length in string in T-SQL using LEN

Tags: sql-server

I have number in string and I need length of number only in string, how can I do that?

```
120 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)
5 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)

select 
  LEN( PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [address])) doorNoLength
```

### output expected

```
i) 3
2) 1
```

Comment: What if you had the address `11a Oxford Road, London, (NW109QT)`; is the expected value 3 or 2? *(Also, on a totally different note, Westminster only has 1 `i`, it's spelt (and pronounced) "mins-ter" not "min-is-ter")*

Comment: Yeah, what is the output for non matching rows?

Comment: Are all the addresses definitely in the format `nnn street name`? Real world addresses like `Flat 7, 12 Acacia Avenue` could certainly not be

Comment: Duplicate of your previous question anyway. If you already have an answer telling you how to extract the relevant part then trivial to add `LEN` to it

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do ?

```
SELECT LEN(LEFT(address, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', address)-1)) AS doorNoLength
```